# Installing on IIS - The page cannot be found

Tags: iis, web

I'm installing an application on IIS and I have double-confirmed that the Default.aspx file is in the directory specified in the Home Directory in the properties of the website, but I keep getting this error, like the file isn't there.  Anyone have any suggestions to why this may be happening?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution was to go into IIS Manager and expand the server in the left pane.  From there, I clicked Web Service Extensions.  In the right pane, I then clicked ASP.NET v4.0.30319 and clicked "Allow".

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the site in question is marked as an application in IIS and that the framework version specified is correct.

Comment: Right click on the site and click "Convert to Application". What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: I figured it out.  See my solution below.  Thanks for your responses!